# I can't import module correctly in macbook terminal

Tags: python, import, module

I recently start using macbook to run my python code. In macbook terminal, I have set my PYTHONPATH by this code in the root directory:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:$/Users/ray
```

Then my .py file working correctly by using absolute path under the root directory:

```
py /Users/ray/PP4E/Gui/Clock/clock.py
```

But when I change the working directory from the root to subdirectory like this:

```
cd /Users/ray/PP4E/Gui/Clock
```

I can't run the clock.py file because 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PP4E''. Then I try set PYTHONPATH like before under the new working directory:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:$/Users/ray
```

But it still can't work correctly. The 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PP4E'' occurred again.

Comment: Remove the dollar sign before your user directory, it shouldn't be there - `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/ray`

Comment: In addition to @IainShelvington's comment I'll point out that you might have figured out what was wrong on your own by executing `echo $PYTHONPATH`. Also, you should have told us which shell you are using (e.g., `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, etc.). Since it looks like you are using as POSIX compatible shell the distinction probably doesn't matter but you should still provide that crucial detail. Not to mention telling us the OS you are using (e.g., `uname -a`).